# Ошибка при установке PyCharmPro

Tags: python, django, pycharm

Мне понадобился PyCharmPro, для работы с Django, я скачал ее, удалил  PyCharm Community которым я раньше пользовался, создаю проект [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И мне выходит вот такое окно с ошибкой [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Жму ОК, выходит вот эта ошибка
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И что самое главное, не создаются файлы, которые создаются при создании Django-проекта, а именно: папки с настройками, папки для шаблонов и файл manage.py

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

С чем это может быть связано и как решить эту проблема?? Буду очень и очень благодарен любой вашей помощи, спасибо!

Спустя больше 2ух часов гаданий методом проб и ошибок я сейчас узнал, что когда я создаю проект Django в строке "Base interpreter", если я выбираю версию python 3.9 и 3, то вылазит эта ошибка, а с версией 2.7 ошибка не вылазит, но нужных папок и файлов от Django все равно нет,НО, когда я делаю тоже самое во втором аккаунте мака, то там все эти файлы есть, с чем это может быть связано? Надеюсь эта инфа вам что то подскажет

Comment: Какую версию PyCharm ты используешь? Обновись на 2020.2 или новое. А так не обязательно создавать проект в IDE, можно в терминале создать виртуальное окружение, установить на него Django и создать проект через `django-admin startproject`. Потом открыть его в PyCharm.

Comment: Через терминал ничего не получалось, я установил официальную пробную версию и все норм